# Is it possible to dynamically replace the script section of an html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax, script-tag

I am starting out a page with some canned/mock data being fed to Chart.JS charts, such as:

```
data: [2755, 2256, 1637, 1608, 1603, 1433, 1207, 1076, 1056, 1048],
```

I want to replace that bogus data with real/live data. Can I replace the `<script>` part of an html page with what is passed back from an AJAX call?

IOW, can I do something like this:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url:
                            '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData"
routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "un", begdate = "bd", enddate 
"ed" })'
                    .replace("un", encodeURIComponent(_unit))
                    .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
                    .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate)),
                        contentType: 'text/plain',
                        cache: false,
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: false
                        },
                        success: function (returneddata) {
                            $("script").html(returneddata);
                            $("#newhourglass").addClass("hide");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log('error in ajax call t
QuadrantData');
                            $("#newhourglass").addClass("hide");
                        }
                    });
```

?

IOW, instead of:

```
$("html").html(returneddata);
```

...or some such, something like this:

```
$("script").html(returneddata);
```

Comment: You don't need to add it to your HTML page, you have your data in returnddata, just assign this to your chart..  eg..  myChart.datasets[0].data = returneddata; myChart.update();.  or something like that.

Comment: instead of setting the script's "html" (which won't execute), you can delete the original script node and create a new one (or just simply "eval()" the modified string).  but a) it's hard to tell if that particular effect will actually get you what you want and b) can't you just modify the chart's data property (vs. trying to edit a script which may/may-not have executed yet)

Comment: long way between simply updating chart data to replacing everything inside html tag. Chart should be able to be reloaded and if not just replace it and initialize it again

Comment: I have three charts on my page, so I can't just assign all the returned data to a single chart. I may have to create three different ajax calls.

Comment: I don't know if I can simply "replace [the chart] and initialize it again", because the chart, from an html statement, is a simple "canvas" tag; what makes it live is the javascript, which provides the chart with data and options, and creates the chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will be adding on to what Travis and other commenters said.

When HTML is being parsed, `script` tags are executed as soon as the closing `script` tag is seen. What is left is just a tag with inner text. I will be demonstrating this behavior with below snippet.

```css
script {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
Below scripts counts upward every second. But editing it wont change its after effects.
<script contenteditable="true">
counter=0;
counterInterval = setInterval(function clicked(){
  console.log(counter++);
},1000);
</script>
```

This snippet features a `contenteditable script`. You can change its contents as you change a textbox. But you will see its effects won't change.

Alternatively, when a new `script` tag is inserted into the page (e.g. with `javascript`), it is executed. Below snippet demonstrates this.

```js
reinsertScripts = function() {
  var script = document.querySelector("#reinsert");
  var parent = script.parentNode;
  var nscript = document.createElement("script");
  nscript.contentEditable = true;
  nscript.id = "reinsert";
  nscript.innerHTML = script.innerHTML;
  parent.removeChild(script);

  parent.appendChild(nscript);
}
```

```css
script[contenteditable="true"] {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Count: </span><span id="counter"></span></p>

Below scripts counts upward every second. Clicking reinsert button will rerun the script and you may see changes.
<script contenteditable="true" id="reinsert">
  counter = 0;
  clearInterval(window.counterInterval);
  counterInterval = setInterval(function clicked() {
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=counter++;
  }, 1000);
</script>

<button onClick="reinsertScripts()">Reinsert script</button>
```

Though this is the answer to your question, I believe this is not the answer you need. Look for "dynamically changing ChartJS data". Basically, you can use `chart.addData` and `chart.removeData` functions to update a chart's data.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I replace the [script] part of an html page with what is passed back from an AJAX call?

No, you cannot. Once a script has been interpreted by the browser it is merely text that is `display: none;`. In fact, you can remove all of your scripts `$('script').remove()` without any effect whatsoever on the page itself.

This is because once the script has executed the environment has been altered depending on what the code was doing and reflects the changes of the executed code.

Instead, you should attempt to change the `data` variable that you already assigned to, and reinitialize the charts with that new data. Alternatively, you could add new charts as the new data came in. Either way, the process for getting the data to show up from the ajax success is going to need to be done in code and not by simply replacing the html of a script tag.

In order to execute any script returned from the ajax call, you can use `.html(htmlWithScriptElements)` on an element placed on the page and jQuery will internally execute the script for you (using `eval`).

Comment: The script has to still be live after being rendered, or click events would not fire. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you...

Comment: "the process for getting the data to show up from the ajax success is going to need to be done in code and not by simply replacing the html of a script tag" Yes, the data is retrieved in a REST method called by Ajax, and returned back. But whether a Chart.JS chart's data property can be assigned that returned data is an open question in my mind.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you're talking about in the last paragraph?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - "still has to be live", nope. Once it is interpreted it is part of that environment. After that, it is just text.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - "whether a Chart.Js chart's data property can be assigned", yes, this is the tricky part. You need to figure out how to reseed the data according to that library's api, and then also using the api have it redraw or update.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - In the last paragraph, perhaps I was unclear. If you get back a view in an ajax success method (since you are using mvc), and it contains both html and script, for example `<div></div><script></script><p></p>`, and you have that view's worth of html in a variable, for example `htmlWithScriptElements`, or more commonly named `data` in the success callback (I think you called it returneddata), if you use `.html(returneddata)` on an element that is on the page, then the script in the `<script>` section of your view will still be executed.

Comment: I am using that synbtax: $("body").html(returneddata); The rest of the page is updated, but the chart does not [re]display.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - Replacing the entire body of the page is a rather drastic replacement. Usually I have a localized area of the page that I replace, and will use `$("#placementArea").html(returneddata)` in order to present the returned view. Even though you are replacing the body of the page, all of the previous script that has executed is still active, and this may cause unintended behavior depending on what was setup.

Comment: I thought you said it was no longer live at that point, "just text" - we obviously have a miscommunication here.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - The effects are still active from being executed, however the script that you would see from the DOM is merely text. Replacing that text will not alter the effects that are active. Executing script to change the effects will change the behaviors though.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - The point of saying it was "just text" was to try to explain that replacing the script or removing the script in itself will not remove the behavior that script created. For example, in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ruhzd6o6/ you can see that it has a simple click event. Note after the click event is wired, all scripts are removed from the page (you can verify by inspection as well). However, clicking on "Hello" will still cause the event handler to execute.